# Rails cache and Nginx rewrite

Tags: caching, mod-rewrite, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a slash in the end of all urls in my site:

```
Url: http://example.com/help/
Rails chache file: public/cache/help.html
```

Here is my Nginx rewrite rule:

```
if ($uri ~* ^(.*)/$) {
  if (-f $document_root/cache/$1.html) {
    rewrite (.*) /cache/$1.html break;
  }
}
```

Its not working because the **$1** comes with the trailing slash... could someone help me with this regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try moving the slash outside of your parenthesis so that it won't be included in $1

```
^(.*)\/$
```

if that doesn't work, match all non-slash chars then one slash char

```
^([^\/]*)\/$
```

Comment: in both regex, **$1** comes with the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this hack

```
module PageCachingHack
  class << self
    def included(base)
      base.alias_method_chain :page_cache_file, :trailing_slash
    end
  end

  private
    def page_cache_file_with_trailing_slash(path)
      name = page_cache_file_without_trailing_slash(path)
      name.gsub!('.html', '/index.html') unless name =~ /index\.html/
      return name
    end
end
ActionController::Caching::Pages::ClassMethods.send(:include, PageCachingHack)
```